# not able to install node_modules

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to install node_module but getting following error:

For example:npm install grunt-preprocess

```
D:\grunt_pre>npm install grunt-preprocess
 npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-preprocess
 npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-preprocess
 npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-preprocess
 npm ERR! Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
 npm ERR!     at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
 npm ERR!     at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:892:19)
 npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
 npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
 npm ERR! or email it to:
 npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

 npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
 npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
 ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "grunt-preprocess"
 npm ERR! cwd D:\grunt_pre
 npm ERR! node -v v0.10.15
 npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.5
 npm ERR! syscall connect
 npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
 npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
 npm ERR!
 npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
 npm ERR!     D:\grunt_pre\npm-debug.log
 npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: Can you try accessing through browser the following url https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-preprocess. Is it returning data ?

Comment: @Chandu it is accessible through the link although I am still getting the same error when testing. Meaning its the github repository or npm is glitching.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The registry URL is pointing to `https`, you could try changing it by

```
npm config set registry="http://registry.npmjs.org/"
```

and then try installing the module. It may be possible that you are behind a proxy that is blocking secure (`https`) connections

If it doesn't work then may be you could manually try to download the current version of the module you are trying to install from the [here](http://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-preprocess/-/grunt-preprocess-2.3.0.tgz)

And run the command `npm install grunt-preprocess-2.3.0.tgz`

Comment: Hi, I got 418 - "I'm a teapot." after changing the URL of registry as you described above.

Comment: I was having the same problem, and when I performed `npm get registry` it was pointing to `http://10.16.240.220/` for some odd reason.

Comment: I changed my internet connection and resolvedthis issue

Answer (score 4):

I also had `ETIMEDOUT` errors and was able to resolve the issue by disabling my router's firewall, rebooting it, and most importantly, configuring the number of simultaneous connections with the following npm command:

```
npm set maxsockets 3
```

This sets a max number of connections of 3, instead of the default 50.
The CLI has been allowing this option since npm@3.8.0. See [this link](https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/5b4e3f3caff1f7ed30281b0b450de056a817bbc5/CHANGELOG.md#limit-concurrent-requests) for further reference.

Answer (score 1):

Try the answer by @ Canmah. If it does not help try to check your proxy configuration.

If there is a proxy,  update the npm registry as mentioned below and then try installing the node module.

```
@ the command prompt update the 
npm config set proxy <proxyserver>:<port>
```

Comment: That's not "Canmah", by the way. It's "Салман", which transliterates to "Salman".

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the exact same thing. Either the module exists but the actual download repository is down or there is a problem with npm at the moment. Try again in a few days or report it to the github link.

Edit:

The error you are getting is a timeout from their server or your connection. It could be because you are behind a firewall/proxy that is stopping your connections.

Comment: FYI, The module installation is working perfectly fine, the repository is not down.

Comment: @Салман I was talking about specifically the download for grunt-preprocess

Comment: Yes, I tried that too. `grunt-preprocess` is getting installed perfectly. How can the repository be up and not work for one module?

Comment: @Салман maybe there is an error in that module? I'm not sure. Although I'm quite sure you're right about it being a proxy related problem.

Comment: See if you can install using the manual method shown in my answer.

Comment: @Салман nope still exactly the same error although starting with: npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/preprocess
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/grunt
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/grunt
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/preprocess
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/grunt
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/preprocess

Answer (score 0):

This might be a problem with module **bin-wrapper** which does not respect proxies and that is why you see the **ETIMEDOUT** error when trying to download.

To solve the issue you can set the environment variable HTTP_PROXY and/ or HTTPS_PROXY.
Works under Windows/ Linux.

[The solved **bin-wrapper** issue.](https://github.com/yeoman/node-jpegtran-bin/issues/33)

[Commit with fix.](https://github.com/yeoman/node-jpegtran-bin/commit/bcb67266)

The code piece in the fix:

```
var proxyServer = process.env.HTTPS_PROXY || 
                  process.env.https_proxy ||
                  process.env.HTTP_PROXY ||
                  process.env.http_proxy;
```