# node.js npm install error connection timed out

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have recently installed Node.js and have npm path set up correctly.
I wanted to execute

```
npm install -g npm
```

but I keep getting npm err! connection timed out issue.
I read other post that has similar problem and people said you can change the proxy config but the problem is that I dont know my proxy server address and port number how do I set it? or how can I correct this problem?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Can you go in through IE and `tools > internet options` and then the connections tab and then lan settings. Is there proxy info in there?

Comment: Take a look in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18229125/890890. It may help you.

Comment: I have seen it but i do not know the proxy server address and port

Comment: @Jackie the setting is grayed out. I am on a LAN and under LAN I do have a address but it says auto assigned "http://autoproxy.abc.com/autoproxy.cgi"

Comment: also is there a particular reason you are using npm to install npm? Are you trying to upgrade or something? Once you get your Proxy info this http://blog.jackiergleason.com/2015/11/how-to-deal-with-proxies-when-using.html might help you

Comment: actually i want to install node-red. npm just to have all the features that npm has because now it is just an empty folder. but even if I did "npm install -g node-red" it would still give me this proxy issue

Comment: For above mentioned proxy situation try this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20379908/6452864

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming it is a offline server you can use the following node module 
https://github.com/arei/npmbox