# Problem Installing Expo-cli in Ubuntu using npm

Tags: react-native, npm, npm-install, expo

I am having an issue when I run `npm install expo-cli --global` I get an error saying **response timeout while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/@expo**

[npm install command shows me the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkKEx.png)

I've tried npm cache clear --force and tried **npm install expo-cli --global** but still, I got the error

Comment: check ur proxy setting. Issue with proxy, if you are behind firewall.

Comment: You should provide the full command you ran and the full output you got in your question.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your computer does not have internet, can you please check well?

If you are connected to the internet, there could be a problem with proxy blocking traffic to https://registry.npmjs.org, [this answer might help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229125/not-able-to-install-node-modules)

Comment: I've install creacte-react-app,without any issue but **expo-cli** is giving me this issue

Comment: @Mizan have you attempted doing the proxy fix described in the answer linked in the above post?

Comment: yes.But it didn't work.I thought  this is my internet connection problem.

Answer (score 0):

The ping is of 30,000 ms which is very high, you might have low internet speed or request is blocked by network.  Please Check your internet connection.